# VisionOS hair skinmeshrenderer disappears but regular mesh renderer does not?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visionos

I've noticed that the hair on my character (as a skin mesh renderer) disappears on VisionOS (but not in editor game or scene view). It does not disappear as a regular mesh renderer. Not a shader issue, since a cube with same material/shader appears in both cases. Bug or some sort of renderer setting issue or whatnot?