# Skin Mesh Renderer Blendshape animations do not show in VisionOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, visionos, visionos-simulator

Skin Mesh Renderer Blendshape animations do not show in VisionOS?!??!

Well, this may be related to how a hair skinmeshrenderer does not show up over a regular face mesh skinmeshrenderer with blendshapes... [VisionOS hair skinmeshrenderer disappears but regular mesh renderer does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77797489/visionos-hair-skinmeshrenderer-disappears-but-regular-mesh-renderer-does-not)

But also I suppose a new kind of character animation paradigm must be used then?